# How to make my Bootstrap 4 popup close after clicking "Esc" key on keyboard, while the popup has a YouTube video embedded as iframe and is paused?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

We use Bootstrap 4, and there is an image that opens a popup when clicked. The popup has a YouTube video embedded into it. Clicking the "Esc" button correctly closes the video, as long as the video iframe is not bothered. But, if we pause the video or interact by clicking "Tab" and then clicking the "Esc" button, the popup doesn't get closed. I've tried `data-keyboard="true"` in HTML, JavaScript, and jQuery versions and it isn't working for me.
Here is the code snippet.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalVideo" data-keyboard="true"></a>

<section class="">
  <div class="container mx-auto">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="modal fade" id="modalVideo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body mb-0 p-0">
              <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" 
                        src="" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; 
                        encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"  
                        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Following is the jQuery

```
var src_culture="https://www.youtube.com/embed/someVideo_x?autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1";
$('#modalVideo').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
  $('#modalVideo iframe').attr("src", "");
  $("body").css("padding-right","0");
});
$("#modalVideo").on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
  $("#modalVideo iframe").attr('src', src_culture);
  $("body").css("padding-right","0");
});
```

Kindly help on making this popup close on clicking "Esc" button after interacting with the `<iframe>`.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is experienced, because the browser focuses the elements in the iframe after clicking on it (in your case the video). When the iframe is focused, all keyboard events go to the code in the iframe, not to your own.

This is not easily solved, because the iframe refers to another server, and most browsers block any scripting access to cross-origins (which is a good thing security wise). The YouTube video is not in your control. However, there are strategies to work around this.

### Refocusing the modal video element

You can try to take the focus back to an element you control, e.g. the #modalVideo element.

**Working solution:** In the following snippet, I set an interval to refocus to the video modal every 100ms, if the currently focused element is an `<iframe>`. Therefore, the focus is on the modal again, which results in all expected bootstrap behavior to work again - including ESC key closing the modal:

```js
const focusTarget = $("#modalVideo");

setInterval(_ => {
    if (document.activeElement.tagName === "IFRAME") {
        focusTarget.focus();
    }
}, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalVideo" data-keyboard="true">Toggle</a>

<section class="">
  <div class="container mx-auto">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="modal fade" id="modalVideo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body mb-0 p-0">
              <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe tabindex="-1" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C7MRkqP5NRI" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-pictuare; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

### Alternative Solutions

If you are not satisfied with this solution, you can try to use `<object>` and `<embed>` tags. With these, you can script event handlers that propagate the KeyPressEvent to the parent (the video modal). Then, it should also behave according to its behaviour defined by bootstrap. This works, because these tags are in your control and no cross-origin policy would interfer with that.

You could also try to use a more sophisticated approach for refocusing to the modal window instead of polling it every 100ms, although this might not prove to be trivial.

**Generally speaking**, I would advise against the use of `<iframe>`'s when it is not required, as they can impose complex problems like the one you are experiencing.

Comment: @peikado Did my answer provide any help/ value to you?